# How to check if an element of a 3d array is empty?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a populated 3d array and a function that prints the selected row of each 2d array but if the selected row (starting from the first array) is empty it should print "row empty" and i can't figure out how to check if it's empty.
I tried the following:

```
void printrow(int X[][4][5], int row){
    if(X[0][row][0]==0){
        cout <<"row empty";
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 5;j++){
                cout << X[i][row][j] << " ";
             }
        }
        cout << endl;  
    }
}
```

Maybe I should use a pointer? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by empty? There is no such thing as an "empty" int.

Comment: I mean that it's initialized but didn't get a value assigned to it, so it's 0 (?)

Comment: If it has been initialized, then it does have a value. You can't "detect" if it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: if you want to check if the element is `0` then that is what your code does. Please include a [mcve] and explain how your code is not doing waht you want it to do, including actual and expected output helps

Comment: So how should I do it? if I have 3 2d arrays and I fill only the first row of each, how do I check if the second row is filled?

Comment: btw you have the indices mixed up, maybe that is the actual problem, array is `int X[][4][5]` but you use `X[i][row][j]` with i up to 4 and j up to 5

Comment: you cannot check if the "row is filled" ! you can check if the elements are equal to `0` and that is what your code does

Comment: You are right, i goes up to 3 not 4 because it selects the array and i have only 3, i fixed that now. However, when I try printing X[0][row][0] it prints a huge negative number.

Comment: You can use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: Solved it. The approach was totally wrong. I solved it by taking the total number of elements and comparing it to the number of columns * selected row. Basically if(n_ele <= 5*row)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

```
void printrow(std::array<std::array<std::array<std::optional<int>, 3>, 4>, 5> X, int row){
    if(!X[0][row][0].has_value()){
        cout <<"row empty";
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 5;j++){
                cout << X[i][row][j].value() << " ";
             }
        }
        cout << endl;  
    }
}
```

Comment: You answer is very good. But the OP is still on C, using C-Style arrays and does not understand pointer decay or the correct way on how to pass a C-Style array by reference or pointer. So, again, good and +1. But OP has other problems . . .